# Writing Arabic Text to PDF using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to write some text to a background image and save it as PDF, I'm using iTextSharp and the following Code:

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("resources\\bg2.png");
    Document document = new Document();
            var pageSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((1122*75)/100, (793 * 75) / 100);
            document.SetPageSize(pageSize);
 iTextSharp.text.Image bg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
 bg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
 var writter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("file.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            document.Open();
 document.Open();
            bg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            document.NewPage();
            document.Add(bg);
            BaseFont Tajawal = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"Resources\Tajawal-Medium 500.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Paragraph paragraphTable1 = new Paragraph();
            paragraphTable1.SpacingAfter = 15;
            PdfContentByte cb = writter.DirectContent;
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.DefaultCell.NoWrap = false; 
            table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
            table.TotalWidth = (image.Width - (image.Width / 3));
            table.AddH1(@"شهادة", new iTextSharp.text.Font(Tajawal));
          table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 60, 420, cb);
            document.Close();
```

and the Method for AddH1 is as following:

```
    public static void AddH1(this PdfPTable table, string Text, iTextSharp.text.Font tajawal)
    {
        tajawal.Size = 26f;
        tajawal.SetStyle(iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
        Phrase ph = new Phrase(Text, tajawal);
        PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell(ph);
        text.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        text.Padding = 6;
        text.Border = 0;
        text.NoWrap = false;
        text.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
        table.AddCell(text);
    }
```

My problem is if I use Tajawal font some of the characters are missing, like the last letter, if i use Tahoma font it works as expected, I'm thinking it might be a problem with encoding, any one faced this before ?

if i use the same font on word, or HTML it works perfectly, one thing to notice here is that Arabic letters can be presented in a separated way or joined together, what i figured out is all characters will not be displayed if typed in separated way, it would only work if its joined.

If i open Character Map i found out the following:

Characters starting from U+0621 to U+0649 are separated form (Does not work)
Characters starting from U+FE82 to U+FEFC are joined form (Works Perfectly)

Comment: Always the last letter or if you move that last letter to the middle of the string the character is still missing but now in the middle?

Comment: the character will be missing no matter the position of it

Comment: Then I expect the font you're using doesn't have a glyph for that character. Maybe only the bold face is missing so you could try not calling SetStyle or calling SetStyle with TextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL to confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: i tried all styles, including removing style, all are the same issue

Comment: I have read some where that Word and Html would compensate for missing characters, I wonder if have missing characters how i can compensate in iTextSharp

Comment: I cannot read Arabic, but I've tried rendering it with iText7 and pdfCalligraph, and this was the [output](https://i.ibb.co/R6ySVVp/Captura-de-ecr-2021-03-18-095039.jpg). Is it correct?

Comment: Thats actually the right output !, I'm using itextSharp the old version, however, I'm so interested in the code you wrote to produce that image, could you please share it?

Comment: @Stacker, no special code. [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph) together with iText 7 just does a better job than iText 5 (what you are using)